# Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted': error

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, my codes are as you see below:

```
class FavoriteBloc extends Bloc<FavoriteEvent, FavoriteState> {
  final SaveMovie saveMovie;
  final GetFavoriteMovies getFavoriteMovies;
  final DeleteFavoriteMovie deleteFavoriteMovie;
  final CheckIfFavoriteMovie checkIfFavoriteMovie;

  FavoriteBloc({
    required this.saveMovie,
    required this.getFavoriteMovies,
    required this.deleteFavoriteMovie,
    required this.checkIfFavoriteMovie,
  }) : super(FavoriteInitial()) {
    on<FavoriteEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is ToggleFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        if (event.isFavorite) {
          await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));
        } else {
          await saveMovie(event.movieEntity);
        }
        final response =
            await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieEntity.id));

        emit(response.fold(
          (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
          (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
        ));
      } else if (event is LoadFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(emit);
      } else if (event is DeleteFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        await deleteFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));
        _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(emit);
      } else if (event is CheckIfFavoriteMovieEvent) {
        final response = await checkIfFavoriteMovie(MovieParams(event.movieId));

        emit(response.fold(
          (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
          (r) => IsFavoriteMovie(r),
        ));
      }
    });
  }

  void _fetchLoadFavoriteMovies(Emitter emit) async {
    final Either<AppError, List<MovieEntity>> response =
        await getFavoriteMovies(NoParams());

    emit(response.fold(
      (l) => FavoriteMoviesError(),
      (r) => FavoriteMoviesLoaded(r),
    ));
  }
}
```

Now I get the error in the photo I will share with you.
[image: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/emitter.dart': Failed assertion: line 114 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':]

I would be very grateful if you can help me for the solution of this error I have written. Many thanks to everyone who helps now

I used many artificial intelligence tools to solve the problem, but it did not give me the solution I wanted.

Comment: Please share all text content **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem